# how to update repository

Tags: updates

I am new in this world. I need help with update my repositories. I can't and I need to install DHCP server. Thanks for you collaboration. Sorry for my bad English, I speak Spanish and I learn this language.

This is my problem:

```
1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [2.800 B]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
```

Comment: You should run `sudo apt update` in the terminal to update your repository.